# Samsung Galaxy Note does not boot after ICS update

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ota-update, samsung-galaxy-note

I've just installed Android 4.0.3 ICS onto my Samsung Galaxy Note with 2.3.6. The installation was done by wifi via official installer. I did not download anything specifically, just got a popup with something like "Do you want to upgrade to 4.0.3?" After answering 'yes', it downloaded some files over wifi, and restarted the phone.

But the restart didn't go well. I can see the initial Samsung animation, but after that the text "Samsung" keeps flashing in the center of the screen and nothing happens. I left it for a couple of hours - no changes. I tried rebooting and even remove battery - the same thing, it does not boot.
I have never rooted the device or replaced the ROM.

What can I do? How can I enter recovery mode or something? I tried to enter safe mode by tapping menu button while booting - didn't work.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1658440
enter recovery and try to wipe data then restart. what you describe is a bootloop after rom update, wiping your data should work.
hope you made a backup!

Comment: were you rooted?

Comment: I think if he was rooted the OTA kies wouldn't update

Comment: Holding `Volume Up` + `Home` + `Power` buttons while turning the phone on should boot it into recovery mode, where as @svarog suggests you can do a wipe.

Comment: @svarog, jlehenbauer, Chahk:
Thanks for your help. I wasn't rooted. Successfully entered recovery mode, then wiped all user data. Then rebooted. Didn't work, the same bootloop occurs.
What should I do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest flashing the stock ICS (or Gingerbread, if you prefer) ROM via Odin.  Full instructions [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1424997).

1. Get the official image from http://www.sammobile.com/firmware/ (search for "N7000" and select the download for the appropriate region.)
2. Download and install the USB drivers (for [32 bit](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOBILES/Samsung/Samsung-Galaxy-S-USB-Driver-for-Windows-x86.shtml) or [64 bit](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOBILES/Samsung/Samsung-Galaxy-S-USB-Driver-for-Windows-x64.shtml) Windows)
3. Download the [Odin tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=815370&stc=1&d=1323799721).
4. Extract the contents of the downloaded ROM and place it somewhere on your PC.
5. Reboot the phone into Download mode (<kbd>Volume Down</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd> buttons.)
6. Run Odin and connect the phone to the PC via USB.  Odin should recognize the phone by showing a yellow `[0:COMX]` sign in one of the "ID:COM" boxes.
7. Select the "PDA" button and browse to the extracted TAR file.
8. Make sure that only two boxes are checked in odin - `Auto Reboot` and `F.Reset Time`.
9. Click "Start".

This should refresh the phone with a brand new OS and all prerequisites.

Answer (score 1):

With the phone off, press power then let go and press and hold home and menu while it boots up.